# CRUD UI bug when applying sortBy

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, lodash

I did a CRUD (UI only) simple component in react, but how do I make the primary contact to be the first one in my table? The app can do crud, check and uncheck primary contact, only one primary contact is allowed in the table.

Working demo
https://codesandbox.io/s/r7kmp9rkom

================================================

I've tried using lodash's sortBy

(Broken demo using sortBy
https://codesandbox.io/s/pjj3098lmx)

line 130

```
 <tbody>
          {sortBy(contacts, o => !o.primary).map((o, i) => {
            return (
              <tr className={classNames({ primary: o.primary })} key={i}>
                <td>{o.name}</td>
                <td>{o.email}</td>
                <td>
                  <button
                    onClick={() =>
                      this.setState({
                        openModal: true,
                        modalAction: "update",
                        selected_contact: o,
                        selected_contact_index: i
                      })
                    }
                  >
                    Edit
                  </button>
                </td>
              </tr>
            );
          })}
        </tbody>
```

But it broke the functionality. I think it has to do with the index problem.

I couldn't solve it I don't know why sortBy doesn't retain the index. Another silly option would be using flexbox order but I hope I could solve it using just javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you told it is an index problem

I have used lodash's uniqueId method to retain `id` value, never use an index as `key` for a dynamic list when we have operations like deleting/updating/adding.

if an app is a server-side render `id` must come from a backend.

```
id: uniqueId("contact_")
```

[Working Demo link](https://codesandbox.io/s/rl99p8rp4n)

```
static defaultProps = {
    data: {
      contacts: [
        {
          name: "James",
          email: "james@havard.edu",
          primary: false,
          id: uniqueId("contact_")
        },
        {
          name: "Mark",
          email: "mark@standford.edu",
          primary: true,
          id: uniqueId("contact_")
        }
      ]
    }
  };


onSaveContact = (action, newContact, newContact_index) => {
    if (action === "add") {
      if (newContact.primary) {
        const setNonePrimary = this.state.contacts.map(o => ({
          ...o,
          primary: false
        }));
        this.setState({
          contacts: [
            ...setNonePrimary,
            { ...newContact, id: uniqueId("contact_") }
          ]
        });
      } else {
        this.setState({
          contacts: [
            ...this.state.contacts,
            { ...newContact, id: uniqueId("contact_") }
          ]
        });
      }
    } else if (action === "update") {
      this.setState({
        contacts: [
          ...this.state.contacts.map((o, i) => {
            if (o.id === newContact_index) {
              return { ...newContact };
            } else {
              if (newContact.primary) {
                return { ...o, primary: false };
              } else {
                return { ...o };
              }
            }
          })
        ]
      });
    } else if (action === "delete") {
      this.setState({
        contacts: [
          ...this.state.contacts.filter((o, i) => {
            if (o.id !== newContact_index) {
              return o;
            }
          })
        ]
      });
    }
```

Comment: why it's so? if I didn't use lodash's sortBy index is working for updating/deleting

Comment: @SharonChai I don't think it works as expected even without using a sortBy method.To confirm to delete the middle item in the list, the last item will be deleted.

Comment: No I did not find the problem like you said.

Comment: @SharonChai this video will idea about reconciliation process for list https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=b8IcYOV5_Rc